# I have some issues with my code

Tags: c#, user-interface, variables, unity-game-engine

This code is from a game I am making. The aim is to collect rocket parts. As the parts are collected they are meant to disappear afterwards, but once you pick up one when you try and collect a second one it doesn't add it to the parts variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collection : MonoBehaviour {

private int Parts;
public Text CountPart;
private string Amount;

void Start ()
{
    Parts = 0;
    SetPartText();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Parts == 10)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("DONE");
    }
}

void OnMouseDown ()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Parts = Parts + 1;
    SetPartText();
}

void SetPartText ()
{
    Amount = Parts.ToString () + "/10";
    CountPart.text = "Rocket Parts Collected: " + Amount;
}
}
```

Comment: `"it doesn't add it to the parts variable"` - What do you mean by that?  What's actually failing here?

Comment: Once the player collects the first out of 10 rocket parts which all contain this script it adds on to the parts variable then disables that rocket part but when the user then goes on to collect a second rocket part it does disable the second rocket part but it doesn't add one to the parts variable

Comment: Sure it does, right here: `Parts = Parts + 1;`  This sounds like a good opportunity for you to start using a debugger.  You can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the runtime values and behavior.  When you do that, where specifically does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What specifically happens and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't know how to use a debugger, I am new to coding. When I remove the line "gameObject.SetActive(false);" The program works correctly but just doesn't disable the rocket parts gameobject as soon as I add that same piece of code back it does remove the gameobject but doesn't at the parts to the parts variable after one rocket part is removed

Comment: Then this is the ideal time to *start* using a debugger, which is by far the most useful and valuable tool in your programming.

Comment: how do I use it

Comment: Depends on the tools you're using.  Visual Studio?  Highlight a line of code where you'd want to "pause" execution to observe the runtime behavior.  Go to the "Debug" menu and place a "breakpoint" on that line.  When you run the code in debug mode, it'll stop on that breakpoint.  You can then use the "Debug" menu to step through the code line by line.  There are other helpful windows to show information about local variables, a console window to execute commands manually while in the debugger, etc.  Look for tutorials on debugging with the tools you're using.

Comment: @Joshua You could reach an appropriate audience for your question if you tag it with a the name of the programming language you are using.

Comment: `Debug.Log()` is also quite useful.

Comment: `gameObject.SetActive(false);` disables your gameObject. You probably never receive a second `OnMouseDown` because of that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to think about the use case here you want to collect the rocket parts and then hide/destroy them and also add a part count in your game object.

but your current code there is an issue you deactivating the current player who collects the parts so when you collect the first part you deactivate the player so you won't able to collect another item.

the solution is to get the reference of the part you collecting and then make it setActive(false)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collection : MonoBehaviour {

private int Parts;
public Text CountPart;
private string Amount;
public GameObject collectedGameObject;
void Start ()
{
    Parts = 0;
    SetPartText();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Parts == 10)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("DONE");
    }
}

void OnMouseDown ()
{
        //here you need to initialize the collectedGameObject who is collected. you can use Raycasts or Colliders to get the refrences.
    collectedGameObject.SetActive(false);
    Parts = Parts + 1;
    SetPartText();
}

void SetPartText ()
{
    Amount = Parts.ToString () + "/10";
    CountPart.text = "Rocket Parts Collected: " + Amount;

}
}
```